# Getting rid of module-specific control logic

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm writing a module that can have some additional functionality if other modules such as Block or Menu are enabled, but I don't want to declare them as a dependency.

Currently I'm using `if(module_exists($module)) { ... }` to provide module-specific functionality within my custom module (in this case, defining a particular view if the module in question is present).

However I've heard that this is not the right way to provide module-specific features, and that instead I should use hooks and plugins. The only problem is that I don't really know what that means or how to get started converting my module to using those instead of `if()`s.

How do I define a custom view that depends on another module without using an `if()`?

One of the things I am trying to do is to expose that module's SQL tables to Views if the module exists, and then define a custom view with those tables.

Comment: What specific functionality are you wanting to add? You may be able use the relevant module hooks, otherwise `module_exists` could be a reasonable solution.

Comment: One of the things I am trying to do is to expose that module's SQL tables to Views if the module exists, and then define a custom view with those tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide Views with your module, dependent on enabled modules, you can implement

[`hook_views_default_views`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7)

> This hook allows modules to provide their own views which can either
>   be used as-is or as a "starter" for users to build from.
>
> This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views_default.inc and it will
>   be auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views_default.inc must be in the directory
>   specified by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the
>   same directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.
>
> The $view->disabled boolean flag indicates whether the View should be
>   enabled (FALSE) or disabled (TRUE) by default.

In that hook implementation, you can check if the relevant module is enabled with `module_exists` or `function_exists` when defining that View or component of the View and return the View definition(s) accordingly.

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, as described above.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you're using `hook_views_default_views`, if so that seems like a reasonable solution. Alternatively, you could use features with a `dependencies[]` declaration in the .info file.

Comment: "...but I don't want to declare them as a dependency." Using `hook_views_default_view()`is part of exposing any custom fields to Views, and isn't really related to checking for the presence of modules like Block or Menu.

Comment: I saw you said you don't want to declare them as a dependency but it's not at all clear why, especially if it was a distinct feature module. hook_views_default_view defines the view, not custom fields, so you can return a view or not depending on available modules.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of `hook_views_data()` instead. The reason I don't want to declare dependencies is because my module is meant to describe the current state of the site, not to alter it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for (or what other people meant when they said that you shouldn't use module_exists() so much) would be to implement hooks "on behalf of" another module.

E.g. Crumbs introduces a hook_crumbs_plugins(), and then it implements this hook on behalf of other modules: menu_crumbs_plugins(), taxonomy_crumbs_plugins(), etc. These hooks will only ever be triggered if the respective other modules are enabled.

Whether this is a good idea, depends. It is ok if you are really confident that the respective module will never ever implement this hook by itself. But you need to be aware that you are intruding in the other module's "namespace".

Module names as function prefixes in D7 are quite fragile anyway compared to real namespaces, so maybe we all don't care so much in D7 and just pray that nothing blows up.

Otherwise I don't think it is all too wrong to use module_exists() where it makes sense.

Next time someone says this is best practice, ask them to explain why! There are a lot of mythical and unquestioned DOs and DONTs floating around in the community..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `hook_views_default_views`, then using `if` `module_exists` is perfectly fine.

See the example how [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module implements that in [`entityform.views_default.inc`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/entityform/tree/views/entityform.views_default.inc?h=7.x-2.x) file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views().
 */
function entityform_views_default_views() {
  $view = new view;
  $view->name = 'entityforms';
  // ...
  /* Display: Master */
  $handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
  $handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'List';
  // ...
  $handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['required'] = 0;

  if (module_exists('views_bulk_operations')) {
    /* Field: Bulk operations: Entityform */
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'entityform';
    // ...
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['force_single'] = 0;
  }

  /* Field: User: Name */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
  // ...
  $handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['name'] = 'management';
  $views[$view->name] = $view;

  return $views;
}
```

Then if another module wants to alter the existing view definition, it can use `hook_views_default_views_alter` in similar way (see [example here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218699/1908)).