# How can I download a results set with a form built in Entity forms?

Tags: 7, entities, importing-exporting

We've tried entity forms for a project and the client wants that collected data in a spreadsheet. (This was never a mentioned spec before the project.)

Is this possible? Is there a way to download entity form submissions to a CSV or spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export): For downloading submissions, [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) support that by default.

Comment: How do I bulk download entityform submissions?

Answer (score 0):

When enabling [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) (VBO) modules, the export of all submission should be visible in form of feed icons on the submission list (as per `entityform.views_default.inc` file).

Although if you'd like to implement selective submission export, you need to modify the `entityforms` view, for example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
  if (module_exists('entityform') && module_exists('views_bulk_operations')) {
    /* Display: Master */
    $handler =& $views['entityforms']->display['default']->handler;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations']['action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action']
      = array(
        'selected' => 1,
        'skip_confirmation' => 1,
        'override_label' => 1,
        'label' => 'Export to CSV',
        'settings' => array(
          'url' => 'entityform-submissions/downloads/[current-page:arg:4]/csv',
        ),
      );

    /* Display: CSV Data export */
    $handler =& $views['entityforms']->display['autofields_csv']->handler;
    /* Contextual filter: Entityform Submission: Entityform submission ID */
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['id'] = 'entityform_id';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['table'] = 'entityform';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['field'] = 'entityform_id';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['entityform_id']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
    $handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'entityform-submissions/downloads/%/csv/%';
    // $handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(); // Removes feed icon.

    /* Display: XML Data export */
    $handler =& $views['entityforms']->display['autofields_xml']->handler;
    // $handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(); // Removes feed icon.
  }
}
```

Place above code in your custom module, e.g. in `views/MYMODULE.views.inc`. Then you need these extra hooks in your `.module` file (to invoke your view changes and make support for tokens for your VBO URL):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/views',
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_drupal_goto_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  if (module_exists('token') && user_access('administer nodes') && strpos($path, '[') !== FALSE) {
    // Required for entityform export pages.
    // E.g. /admin/structure/entityform_types/manage/%/submissions.
    $path = token_replace($path);
  }
}
```